# Adding custom param to Mongoose schema

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema, custom-properties

I'm working on an express API using Mongoose Schema.

When creating for example a "user", I would like to check that my request.body do not contain field that I do not want user to edit.

I was thinking about using the Mongoose schema by adding some custom param, like this:

```
const schema = new mongoose.Schema({
name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    -> input: true
},
email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    -> input: true
},
protected_field: {
    type: String,
    -> input: false
},
...
```

So based on that login, I would be able to check the request.body of POST /users and return an error in case there is a "protected_field" key inside of it.

Is this possible? Or any better way to achieve it?

Thanks